# Problem Installing Linux on New Laptop

Tags: system-installation

There is problem installing Linux(ubuntu,debian,opensuse and others) on new laptops like *Asus N76VB-T5012H*, *Asus X75VC-TY006H* and *MSI CR70 2M-206FR*.

On boot, you're asked either to try or install but none works. The screen stays grey and you can only turn off the computer. Can you help me or tell me if this (new) problem is known?

Comment: Have you checked the validity of the .ISO file you created the LiveCD/LiveUSB you installed Ubuntu with (thats the usual way to install Ubuntu) via MD5 or SHA-125? Sometimes while the ISO is being downloaded the internet "hiccups" and the download glitches just enough to cause a minor problem like this. Read this for help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: It takes a while to load up, with no hint of it doing so. Wait 15mins max for an old computer, it'll probably load eventually. If it still doesn't load, the problem will be with something else.

Comment: Do you know whether your system is a x32 or x64 and that you have the right installation as per to your system?  x64 Ubuntu will not work on x32.